# Comparability of vector spaces over the same field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cardinals

Let $V$ be the collection of linear isomorphism classes of vector spaces over field $F$. Is this class $V$ totally ordered by inclusion?

Argument (possibly erroneously):

(The following assumes that the vector spaces in consideration are all over the same field.)

Does there exist an embedding map between any two vector spaces? My reasoning is that, this holds for finite dimensions and since every vector space has a basis (assuming Zorn's lemma), the difference between any two vector spaces  essentially lies in the cardinality of the bases, so if the cardinality itself is ordered (assuming Continuum Hypothesis?) then we should be able to compare any two vector space and say that one of them is contained in the other.

I was in particular thinking about the normed linear spaces but in that case this seems to fail due to the fact that same vector space can be endowed with different topologies by different norms and we can can construct incomparable topologies using inequivalent norms.

PS: Please excuse the general nature of the question. Since I am not entirely proficient at cardinal arithmetic and topics like Continuum Hypothesis, I am chasing my idea based on the little that I know.

Comment: starting with $V$ is not a set, but a proper class ...

Comment: I'm assuming you mean to show that the collection of linear isomorphism classes of vector spaces over F is totally ordered by inclusion?

Comment: @SinisterCutlass :Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, as remarked in the comments, the collection of all vector spaces over a fixed field is a proper class and not a set. But we can still ask whether it is totally ordered by some relation or not.

Secondly, and more importantly perhaps, is to understand the difference between *inclusion* and embedding (via an injective linear homomorphism). Inclusion means that one vector space is literally a subset of another. But since *every* large enough set can be endowed with a vector space structure over your fixed field (all it has to do is be as large as the field), this means that "most sets" can be made into a vector space. So inclusion certainly does not order the vector space via a linear ordering.

So what about embedding? Well, here you get the same problem you get with infinite sets in general. You can easily write an injective linear map between two different vector spaces (and you can also have that neither of the two maps you wrote is an isomorphism). So you get that injective linear maps do not define a partial order, but rather a quasi-order.

But now what? Well, assuming the axiom of choice, every vector space has a basis with a unique cardinality, also known as the dimension of the space. Now it's easy. Since cardinals are linearly ordered, assuming the axiom of choice, the possible dimensions are also linearly ordered, so if you think about isomorphic vector spaces as "being the same", it follows that injective linear homomorphism do in fact linearly order the class of $F$-vector spaces. Note that this has nothing to do with the continuum hypothesis.

Finally, what happens if we do not assume the axiom of choice? Well, then it's possible that there are vector spaces without a basis; or vector spaces with two bases of different cardinalities (so dimension is not a well-defined notion); or just vector spaces that do not have any injective linear maps between one another. So essentially, wherever you've used choice, you had to use choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It took me some time to digest. The notion that a big enough set can be given the vector space structure is new to me. Do you mean that we can define the vector space _freely_ over the set? If that is the case then surely the restriction that the set be as big as the field is unnecessary, isn't it? So, since the natural numbers are in bijection with the rationals so can $N$ be thought of as a vector space over $Q$?

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb N$ can be made into a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ (note that $\Bbb N$ will *not* preserve its usual structure!!!). In fact, an infinite dimensional one, if you want it to be. But the set $\{0,1,2\}$ cannot be made into a vector space over $\Bbb Q$ (it is true, however, that *any* singleton can be made into a $0$-dimensional vector space over any field whatsoever, and there is a proper class of these already).

Comment: So the vector space will be same as the one generated by any countably infinite set over $Q$ (since the only characteristic of $N$ that remains after removing its usual structure is its cardinality)?

Comment: Yes. As I wrote, any sufficiently large set (which is at least as large as the field) can be endowed with a suitable vector space structure. In fact with many different (but possibly isomorphic) vector space structures.

Comment: I am probably dragging this a bit, but can you suggest how to go about in the case the set is with $n(>p)$ elements over the field $F_p$?

Comment: Your answer points out that problems can happen with the existence of bases when we don't assume choice, but using bases was just one approach to the argument, right?  In other words, how do we know that we *had* to use choice?

Comment: @LSpice: Well, it is consistent that over a finite field $F$ there is a vector space which is Dedekind-finite, and there's always one that is countable. So easily those are incomparable. We can stretch that argument and use slightly better results to get more out of it. But at the very least it shows that a general argument won't work without AC. It should also be true in general that if AC fails there is a field with two incomparable vector spaces, but I just got out of bed not too long ago, so we can try that later.